# Creating new user by creating new folder

Tags: users, authentication, administration

I would like to ask a doubt regarding the creation of new user in Ubuntu. Normally we use "Users and Group" GUI application, terminal, etc for creating new users. But I would like to know, can we create a new user by just creating a new folder in `/home` by entering in it as an administrator? Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, creating a home directory doesn’t create a user account; if you try, you’ll see that after creating the directory, you can’t `chown` it to the user because the user doesn’t exist.

Users are defined by entries in the `passwd` database, which can take various forms; one of them is `/etc/passwd`, along with `/etc/shadow` (which stores passwords) and `/etc/group` (which stores the group database).

On Ubuntu, you can use `adduser` to create users without using the GUI; see `man adduser` for details. It will also take care of creating home directories and populating them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Thanks for your time and consideration. Regards.